# XMPP with aSmack library getting error?

Tags: android, client, xmpp

I am trying to make aSmack work in my project. Created a standard project in eclipse, added the jars (smack.jar, smackx-debug.jar, smackx-jingle.jar, smackx.jar) to libs folder . Started using the XMPP classes, but I am not sure if there's something else I should do to properly set up the project (later on that), since it's not working. when i run the app i am getting this error `Could not find class 'java.beans.PropertyDescriptor', referenced from method org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils.parseWithIntrospection`, when i try to send message i am getting this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.`and `at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:445)`

this is the code i am using

```
public  class ClientJabberActivity extends Activity {

   private  final  static String server_host =  "aaaaa.com" ;
   private  final  static  int SERVER_PORT =  5222 ;
   private  final  static String SERVICE_NAME =  "gmail.com" ;  
   private  final  static String LOGIN =  "xxxx@name.com" ;
   private  final  static String PASSWORD =  "yyyy";

   ArrayList<String> m_discussionThread;
   ArrayAdapter<String> m_discussionThreadAdapter;
   XMPPConnection m_connection;
   private Handler m_handler;   

   @ Override 
   public  void  onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   super . onCreate (savedInstanceState);
   setContentView (R.layout.main);
   m_handler =  new  Handler ();
     try  { 
        initConnection ();
     }  catch (XMPPException e) { 
        e. printStackTrace ();
     }

    final EditText recipient = (EditText) this . findViewById (R.id.recipient);
    final EditText message = (EditText) this . findViewById (R.id.message);     
    ListView list = (ListView) this . findViewById (R.id.thread);

    m_discussionThread =  new ArrayList<String>();
    m_discussionThreadAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>  ( this ,
            R.layout.multi_line_list_item,  m_discussionThread);
    list.setAdapter(m_discussionThreadAdapter);

    Button send = (Button) this . findViewById (R.id.send);
    send. setOnClickListener ( new View. OnClickListener () { 
        public  void  onClick (View view) {                 

            String to = recipient.getText().toString ();
            String text = message.getText().toString ();

            Message msg =  new  Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody(text);
            m_connection.sendPacket (msg);
            m_discussionThread. add ( " Me  : " );
            m_discussionThread. add (text);
            m_discussionThreadAdapter. notifyDataSetChanged ();
         } 
    } );
 }

private  void  initConnection () throws XMPPException { 

    ConnectionConfiguration config = new  ConnectionConfiguration (server_host, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
    m_connection =  new  XMPPConnection (config);
    m_connection.connect ();
    m_connection.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD);
    Presence presence =  new  Presence(Presence.Type.available);
    Log.i("ID", ""+presence);
    m_connection.sendPacket (presence);       

    PacketFilter filter =  new  MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);

    m_connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                m_discussionThread.add(fromName + ":");
                m_discussionThread.add(message.getBody());

                m_handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                m_discussionThreadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                });
            }
        }
    }, filter);

ChatManager chatmanager = m_connection.getChatManager();
  chatmanager.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener()
  {
    public void chatCreated(final Chat chat, final boolean createdLocally)
    {
      chat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener()
      {
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message)
        {
          System.out.println("Received message: " 
            + (message != null ? message.getBody() : "NULL"));
          Log.i("CHAT USER", "Received message is: "+message.getBody());
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
}
```

Anybody have experienced this problem in your XMPP client. is it problem in jar files or anything i have to change any thing in my code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using the asmack jars and not the smack jars? because this error looks something that you will get if you are using normal smack.

Comment: As Steffen said you seem to use hte wrong jars. Use this jar http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/libs/asmack-android-5.jar it is usually the most uptodate.

Comment: ya i did a mistake in jar files now its working for gmail account but not my server account what will be the problem....

Comment: Good. About your question. you have to explain more clearly what the problem is now.

Comment: @Jug6ernaut your link is broken, can you suggest some alternative?
or upload jar to dropbox and share?